# How to read a stream with Python 3? (not with requests module)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, client, http-streaming

I'm building an HTTP client that reads a stream from a server. Right now I am using the `requests` module, but I am having trouble with `response.iter_lines()`. Every several iterations I lose data.

Python Ver. 3.7

requests Ver. 2.21.0

I tried different methods, including the use of generators (which for some reason raise a `StopIteration` for very small amounts of iterations). I tried setting `chunk_size=None` in order to prevent losing data but the problem still occurs.

```py
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True, timeout=60 * 10)
    gen = response.iter_lines(chunk_size=None)
    try:
        for line in gen:
            json_data = json.loads(line)
            yield json_data
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

```py
def http_parser():
    json_list = []    
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True, timeout=60 * 10)
    for line in respone.iter_lines():
        json_data = json.loads(line)
        json_list.append(json_data)
    return json_list
```

Both functions cause loss of data.

In the `requests` documentation it is mentioned as a warning that iter_lines() may cause loss of data. 
Does anyone have a recommendation of another module that has a similar ability that won't cause any loss of data?